# How to open and read .UPER file

Tags: asn.1, hexdump

I have an .**UPER** file which contains binary value. In fact, this file is encoded asn 1 file. I searched on internet but I couldn't find any specific application to open and read this type of file. I just heard about **hexdump**. but I not sure about that and also I couldn't understand how to use it. I appreciate any help.

Comment: You could try [ASN.1 Editor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4910/ASN-Editor)

Answer (score 1):

A free web application that can do this is available at:

http://obj-sys.com/webtools/asn2xml.php

Other tools that can do this may be found at:

http://www.itu.int/en/ITU-T/asn1/Pages/Tools.aspx

Some are free, but most are not.

Answer (score 1):

To read the information in the .uper file in a meaningful way, you need two things.  The ASN.1 specification used to create the .uper file, and an ASN.1 toolkit that supports the unaligned PER encoding rule.  There is a free online ASN.1 compiler and encoder/decoder you can try once you find the ASN.1 specification.  It is at http://asn1-playground.oss.com.  You can also find an list of ASN.1 Tools at http://www.itu.int/en/ITU-T/asn1/Pages/Tools.aspx (some free, some commercial).